# Need to set bool with cross-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, boolean, variable-assignment

```
private bool getWindowBool() {
    bool myBool;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => myBool = IsForegroundWindow));
    return myBool;
}
```

why doesn't this work? How would I do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Definite assignment. The compiler doesn't know what Invoke means here, and it doesn't try to understand that the delegate gets invoked before the end of the method - so it can't prove (with the limited processing) that it is assigned before the return. Change to:

```
bool myBool = false;
```